# gfortran: What are the differences between "-Wl,-rpath,..." and "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=..."?

Tags: gfortran, hdf5

### First Method (export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH):

Based on this method, I can compile h5_crtdat.f90 through "gfortran h5_crtdat.f90 -fintrinsic-modules-path /usr/local/include -lhdf5_fortran" successfully. And I can run it as well.

### Second Method (-Wl,-rpath):

Based on this method, I can compile h5_crtdat.f90 through "gfortran h5_crtdat.f90 -fintrinsic-modules-path /usr/local/include -lhdf5_fortran -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib" successfully. However, after type in "./a.out" I got the following error
***"./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5.so.200: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"***.

### Questions:

I have searched the google that these two methods can produce the same effect when linking shared library in gfortran compiler. Thus, I do not know why I will get the errors when the second method is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two serve a different purpose.

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` says where to search for shared libraries when executing some executable that has already been compiled and linked. It is possible, but not guaranteed, that some linker will alsonconsider this path for the actual linking, but there are other variables, like `LIBRARY_PATH` for that.

`-Wl,-rpath` says where to link shared libraries when building the executable. It has no effect when running the executable.

You must set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or some equivalent when running the executable so that the necessary libraries for the run can be located.

Comment: Sorry for not replying in time. Thanks for your answer, and I have already known what they are for.